# Zend framework: how to reset mysite.com/admin/auth password in mysql using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, phpmyadmin

I have never used Zend framework but I've inherited a site from another developer and need to log in to: `mysite.com/admin/auth`.

I've created a username and password in the user table in phpMyAdmin (using md5 for the password) but I still can't log in (`Invalid credentials provided`). Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you know what version of ZF? You need to figure out what authentication method the app is using. E.g. if it's using salted passwords, or something other than md5, your method won't work. Ideally the app would have some sort of signup/register form that you could use instead.

Comment: Bare with me - this is the version?:

Comment: version    $Id: Config.php 12204 2008-10-30 20:42:37Z dasprid $

Comment: I think it is using salt - // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($registry->db);
        $authAdapter
            ->setTableName('dealer')
            ->setIdentityColumn('username')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password')
            ->setIdentity($username)
            ->setCredential(md5($password.$registry->config->catalog->salt))
        ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name in your comment indicates that the app is using ZF1. Since the password is salted, first you need to find the salt. It's coming from a config - see if the app has an `application/configs` folder (which is the ZF1 convention). Otherwise, just check the source code for "salt" and you should find it.

It is using md5, so once you have the salt, you should be able to create the password as you were before - just append the salt onto the end of your password. E.g. if your password was "phillystyle" and the salt was "ABCDEFG123", set the password to `md5('phillystyleABCDEFG123')`.

Comment: Thanks so much -that was exactly it! Just to clarify, after updating the password in the db, I only use: phillystyle as the password when logging in. Thanks tons!